# Why do I get the error `undefined method 'map'`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

In my Ruby on Rails application I am trying to display a three drop down menus in the _form.html.erb which are rendered from the file _booking_lookup.html.erb and get there data from the drop down menu methods in the models.

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= render(:partial => '/booking_lookup', :locals=> {:film => @film = Film.all, :showings => @showings = Showing.all, :seats => @seats = Seat.all, :my_path => '/films/booking_lookup' }) %>
```

_booking_lookup.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag my_path, :method=>'post', :multipart => true do %>
<%= select_tag ('title_id'), 
    options_from_collection_for_select(@films, :id, :title_info, 0 ),
    :prompt => "Film" %>

<%= select_tag ('showings_id'), 
    options_from_collection_for_select(@showings, :id, :showing_times, 0 ),
    :prompt => "Showings" %> 

<%= select_tag ('seat_id'), 
    options_from_collection_for_select(@seats, :id, :seats_available, 0 ),
    :prompt => "Seats" %> 

<%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
```

film.rb:

```
class Film < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :showings
belongs_to :certificate
belongs_to :category

def title_info
     "#{title}"
end
end
```

seat.rb:

```
class Seat < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :screen
has_many :bookings

def seats_available
    "#{row_letter}#{row_number}"
end
end
```

showing.rb:

```
 class Showing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :film
  has_many :bookings
  belongs_to :screen

    def showing_times
        "#{show_date.strftime("%e %b %Y")} @ #{show_time.strftime("%H:%M")}"
    end
end
```

But for some reason with the line: `<%= select_tag ('title_id'), 
        options_from_collection_for_select(@films, :id, :title_info, 0 ),
        :prompt => "Film" %>` I get the error:

```
NoMethodError in Bookings#new 
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

The weird part is that I am using a lot of this code else where, I have a _multi_search.html.erb form:

```
 <%= form_tag my_path, :method=>'post', :multipart => true do %>
 <!--  Genre: -->
 Search By:
 <%= select_tag ('cat_id'), 
    options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :id, :category_info, 0 ),
    :prompt => "Genre" %>

<%= select_tag ('cert_id'), 
    options_from_collection_for_select(@certificates, :id, :certificate_info, 0 ),
    :prompt => "Age Rating" %> 

<%= text_field_tag :search_string, nil, placeholder: "ACTOR" %>
or
<%= select_tag ('title_id'), 
    options_from_collection_for_select(@films, :id, :title_info, 0 ),
    :prompt => "Film" %>
<%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

And is used in the application.html.erb:

`<%= render(:partial => '/multi_search', :locals=> {:categories => @categories = existing_genres, :certificates => @certificates = Certificate.all, :films => @films = Film.all, :my_path => '/films/multi_find' }) %>`

And that works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check if @films is nil?

Comment: No I did not, but I am sure it is not nil. What is weird is I've got something similar working else where and that works fine - I'll include this in the original question.

Comment: `@films` **is** nil - you're setting `@film = Film.all`, not `@films = Film.all`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `@films` is nil. Try setting `@films = Film.all` (instead of `@film = Film.all`) in _form.html.erb.

**Update**:

I would recommend moving the queries to the controller action. In the Model-View-Controller pattern, Controllers should be asking Models for data, not Views.

```
# BookingLookupController
def new
  @films = Film.all
  @showings = Showing.all
  @seats = Seat.all
end
```

You can then reference the instance variables in the view.

```
<%= render partial: '/booking_lookup', locals: {films: @films, showings: @showings, seats: @seats, my_path: '/films/booking_lookup' } %>
```

Comment: I can't believe I made that mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a 2nd pair of eyes. =)

Answer (score 0):

In Controller, select fields as you just want to display names in dropdown

```
def method_name
   @films = Film.select([:id, :title_info])
   @showings = Showing.select([:id, :showing_times])
   @seats = Seat.select([:id, :seats_available])
end
```

In page

```
<%= render(:partial => '/booking_lookup', :locals=> {:films => @films, :showings => @showings, :seats => @seats, :my_path => '/films/booking_lookup' }) %>
```

In partial

```
 options_from_collection_for_select(films, :id, :title_info, 0 ),:prompt => "Film" %>
```

Comment: Please use controllers for communicating with the Models. Never try these type of active record method invocation from view, it's a very bad practice.